# tksvg - _tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file libtksvg.so

Tags: python, tksvg

I'm preparing small program for barcode generation. I prepared GUI in custom tkinter and I have barcode in svg file.

I'm trying to use tksvg to load svg files. For some time it was possible when I run program as normal user, but it was impossible as admin (sudo python ...).
I reinstall tksvg but now I have the same error on both users (normal and admin):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/laser/barcode_generator_picture.py", line 27, in <module>
    svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage(file="barcode.svg", scale=3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tksvg/__init__.py", line 50, in _   _init__
    load(master)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tksvg/__init__.py", line 27, in l   oad
    window.tk.eval("package require tksvg")
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tk   svg/libtksvg.so": /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tksvg/libtksvg.so: cann   ot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x7f8d35ddc0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4015, in __del__
    if self.name:
AttributeError: 'SvgImage' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What should I do to load svg files?

Comment: I would update your python to a build that at uses Tk 8.6. You are using Tk 8.5 which is from 2007. Just going up to python 3.10 will bring you to the next Tk version.

Comment: I install fresh, new Raspbian with Python 3.11 and tck/tk 8.6 and now program works nice! Thank you!